# python FTP to mainframe is working in windows but not in docker container

Tags: python, docker, ssl-certificate, mainframe, zos

I am trying to pull a file from mainframe using python ftplib. I am able to login and pull file from mainframe in my local machine, but i am able to connect to host but i am getting error (SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)during login command.

```py
from ftplib import FTP
ftps=ftplib.FTP_TLS()
ftps.connect(host,port)
ftps.login(user,passwd)
```

PS. i have python 3.9.7 version in my local, 3.10 version in docker. i have copied the same cacert to docker image. could you please help in understanding and resolve the issue

i tried with different ssl protocol version still i am not able to get over the issue.

Comment: Have you also installed the ca-cert you copied over? In ubuntu base images this is usually done by putting `RUN update-ca-certificates` after copying in the cert.

Comment: Yes I copied and run certificates in docker file